# Combination of element in array, for getting factors of number

Tags: java, combinations

I want a combination algorithm,...to multiple the elements in the array, to every other element but itself....

please help me to combine eg:: {1,2,3,4,5,6}

output:: 1*2,1*3....1*6, 1*2*3 !*2*4.......1*2*3*4*5*6.......5*6

code removed it was irrelevant to my logical requirement of question...

Comment: Don't use `log` or `pow` if you want it to be fast. ;)  You may find that trying all the factors up to a number is faster because it simpler.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, i know that, just wanted to see how this would work

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, thanks, I got ans have to use recursion n similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310209/stuck-with-combination-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
//This method return a list of lists, where each "inner list" contains as
//its first number the number for which the factors are being found, and
//every other number is a factor.
//It takes an array of all the numbers whose factor you wish to find
public List<List<Integer>> getAllFactors(int[] toCalculate){
    List<List<Integer>> toReturn = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> factors;
    for(int i = 0; i < toCalculate.length; i++){
        factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        factors.add(toCalculate[i]); //add the number whose factors will be calculated
        //the square root is used because it is the largest number you can divide by without getting "overlap"
        for(int j = 1; j <= Math.sqrt(toCalculate[i]); j++){ 
            if(toCalculate[i]%j==0){ //if it divides evenly, add it
                factors.add(j);
                factors.add((Integer)toCalculate[i]/j); //also add its "partner" number
            }
        }
        toReturn.add(factors);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

I put in class `Test`... Here is my testing method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Test t = new Test();
    List<List<Integer>> blah = t.getAllFactors(new int[]{10, 12, 1, 5});
    for(List<Integer> i: blah)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i.toArray(new Integer[i.size()])));
}
```

I realized that this wasn't what the question asked for... I think... I can't really tell...
Anyway, I wrote an alternative method:

```
public List<Integer> getAllFactors(int number){
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++){
        if(number%i==0){
            factors.add(number);
            factors.addAll(getAllFactors(i));
            factors.addAll(getAllFactors(number/i));
        }
    }
    if(factors.isEmpty())
        factors.add(number);
    return factors;
}
```

But then I realized that might not be what you want either.  The fact is, I actually have no fricking clue what you are looking for, I can't understand your post.  I have just been trying to glean info from the comments.

Comment: oh, sorry, my Internet connection was broken, ur 1st answer itself would satisfied my query, it was great piece of code, I was tiring something similar but just more lines of code...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just declare `arr` as a `Set` from the start?

```
Set<Integer> arr = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
```

And leave it at that. You never want duplicates, and if order is important, a LinkedHashSet preserves insertion order.

Comment: ok,thanks,good point,i ll modify it, can u hnit me the way of combining efficiently...

Answer (score 1):

First, finding factors.  Here is a fragment from my own code.  It builds a list of factors of `target` in an `ArrayList` called `factors`.  As each factor is found it is recorded once and divided out as many time as is needed.  The upper limit is then reduced accordingly.  The variable `residue` holds the unfactored portion of `target`.

```
int trialFactor = 0;
int residue = target;
limit = iSqrt(residue);
while (trialFactor < limit) {
    trialFactor = nextPrime(trialFactor);
    if (residue % trialFactor == 0) {
        factors.add(trialFactor);
        do {
            // Remove repeated factors.
            residue /= trialFactor;
        } while (residue % trialFactor == 0);
        limit = iSqrt(residue);
    }
}
// Record largest factor, if present.
if (residue > 1) { factors.add(residue); }
```

There are two of my own functions used:

`int nextPrime(int)` which returns the next highest prime.

`int iSqrt(int)` which returns the integer square root; `iSqrt(10)` returns 3.

Now for the second part of your question, combinations.  You have a group of items and you want all the possible combinations.  If there are n items then just iterate through all the numbers 0 to (2^n) - 1.  That will give you all the bit patterns from 000 ... 000 to 111 ... 111.  For each position in your group a '0' means not to include it in your output while a '1' means to include it.

So, given your {1,2,3,4,5,6} example, you need numbers from 0 to 2^6 - 1 = 63.  Take an example, 45 is 101101 in binary, so your output for 45 is {1,3,4,6}.

Comment: it just calculates the prime factors of Number.... not all factors, I need all factors

Comment: Then record all the prime factors, including duplicates.  Move the `factors.add(trialFactor);` line inside the inner do-loop.  A factor of 4 will be recorded as {2,2}

Comment: 15(3*5), still requires combination, and how to do it is exactly my question

Comment: You have {1,2,3,4,5,6}.  Extract one element: {1} leaving {2,3,4,5,6}.  Use the integer technique to find all combinations of {2,3,4,5,6} and multiply each of those combinations by {1}.  Now repeat for {2}, {1,3,4,5,6} and so on.